# javascript can't use input to grab an object property

Tags: javascript, html, variables, object

So i've got this code below (all javascript). And I wish to grab the votecount for a game on user input

```
function Game(gamename,votes) {
    this.gamename = gamename;
    this.votes = votes;
};

var lol = new Game("League of Legends",1100);
var dota = new Game("DOTA 2",2100);
var ql = new Game("Quakelive",3100);
var csgo = new Game("Counter Strike: GO",4100);

function PostVotes(gnshort){
    //string names - working
    console.log(gnshort + 'name');
    console.log(gnshort + 'votes')

    var CalcVotes = function(gnshort){
        var votecount = gnshort.votes;
        console.log(votecount);
    }

    CalcVotes(gnshort);
    //CalcVotes(lol); //works

};

PostVotes('lol');
```

I keep getting the error undefined when calling CalcVotes(gnshort). and I know it's not the function it's passing the lol as gnshort it's asif it's reading as a string instead of a variable or something. I've only been learning javascript for the past week so any advice would be helpful

Comment: if you have object `lol` why you pass to `PostVotes` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostVotes('lol'); will pass lol as a string ('lol' is equivalent to "lol"). What you need to do is simply pass the variable lol like

```
PostVotes(lol);
```

And it will return lol.votes, aka 1100.

Comment: thanks mate. I ended up passing two inputs one as a string and one as a variable. Great work thank you so much